# Is convex function? (related to sup.)

Tags: convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum

$p(\alpha)= \sup_{x} xf(\alpha) \\
\quad \quad\quad \text{s. t.} \quad x \leq h(\alpha)$

where $f(\alpha)$ is convex function of $\alpha$ and $h(\alpha)$ is non convex function of $\alpha$.

Is $p(\alpha)$ convex function?

Comment: Where did you find this and  have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $f(x)=x^{2}, h(\alpha)=-1$. Then $p(\alpha)=-\alpha^{2}$ which is not convex.In general, for any non-negative convex function $f$,  $p(\alpha)=f(\alpha) h(\alpha)$ and product of a non-negative convex function and an arbitrary function need not be convex.

Comment: $p(\alpha)=f(\alpha) h(\alpha)$ only if $f$ is nonnegative

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks. I have edited my answer.